# cloudSearch:ranging the distance between 0 to some value

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I want to include the documents which has distance < 500 but I am getting all the documents pls help

```js
http://search-vegme-user-7l3rylms73566frh4hwxblekn4.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?

q=fname:'nikhil' &
expr.distance=haversin(35.621966,-120.686706,latlong.latitude,latlong.longitude)<=500&
sort=distance asc&q.parser=structured&
return=displayname,profileimageurl,distance
```

[Click here to Run it](http://search-vegme-user-7l3rylms73566frh4hwxblekn4.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=fname:'nikhil'%20&expr.distance=haversin(35.621966,-120.686706,latlong.latitude,latlong.longitude)%20%3C=%20500&sort=distance%20asc&q.parser=structured&return=displayname,profileimageurl,distance)

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the url to see the answer it also shows how to use structured query

```js
http://search-vegme-user-7l3rylms73566frh4hwxblekn4.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?
q=(and 'nikhil' (and diet:'Vegetarian'(and categoryids:0)))
&q.parser=structured
&expr.distance=haversin(35.621966,-120.686706,latlong.latitude,latlong.longitude)
&sort=distance asc&return=distance,displayname,profileimageurl
```

after this you need to  user if and for to filter the distance

Comment: You should be able to define a ranker based on distance such that it sufficiently penalizes docs outside your threshold to the point that they are not considered matches.